# Can Three.js/WebGL render complicated SVGs made with Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: javascript, svg, three.js

I am trying to design a web page with a bunch of different SVG illustrations using Three.js and WebGL cameras to navigate throughout them. However, the more I research rendering SVGs, the more I realize that the way Adobe exports these SVGs may not be readable by Three.js. I initially drew these images on Adobe Illustrator Draw on the iPad, so theres tons of non-standard, organic strokes. For instance, attached is one of the illustrations I hope to use.

[image]

This results in some pretty complicated code, which is over 3,000 lines. You can find the code here for the above SVG image for reference:

https://jsfiddle.net/hjnrmfe3/1/

What I've tried to do so far is using a URL linking to a file with the 3,000 lines of code to load the SVG with Three.js, because pasting that within the JS file would be a nightmare. However, I haven't managed to make it work. The only instance I've been able to make it load is to use a TextureLoader, which results in a completely grainy image and defeats the purpose of having the illustrations in SVG format, as shown below:

```js
function init() {
  
  container = document.querySelector( '#viewport' );
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var fieldOfView = 75;
  var aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  var nearPlane = 0.1;
  var farPlane = 10000;

  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    fieldOfView, aspectRatio, nearPlane, farPlane
  );

  camera.position.z = 1;

  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
  var canvasWidth = window.innerWidth
  renderer.setSize( canvasWidth, 2000); 

  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

  //image
  var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    map: loader.load(""),
  });

  var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(5, 2.5);

  var desk = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  desk.position.set(0,0,0)

  scene.add(desk);

  var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 0 );
  light.position.set(1, 1, 100 );
  scene.add(light)  


  function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
  }
  animate();

}

init();
```

```css
#viewport {
    position: fixed;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="viewport"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/91/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/SVGRenderer.js"></script>
```

So, I'm curious - is it possible to render these complex SVGs from Adobe Illustrator with Three.js? I plan on using about 10-15 of these style illustrations whose code looks the same way. What is the best way to go about doing this, if its possible?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I've tested your SVG file with [SVGLoader](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_svg) but unfortunately I was not able to load the file correctly. I just see a black square. Consider to report this issue at github.This could be a bug or just a missing feature in `SVGLoader` which could be added in the future.

Comment: To achieve an answer to your more general question, "is it possible to render these complex SVGs from Adobe Illustrator with Three.js?" I suggest creating a simple SVG in Illustrator, and trying to load it in Three.js. If it loads successfully, Then you can continue adding components with "non-standard" representations, and see what breaks. That would be a big boon to any bug report if you can say exactly what elements are breaking.